# Redirect to a different page after a Success Sweet Alert is closed

Tags: javascript, redirect, sweetalert, sweetalert2

For some reason, the following code isn't working for me even though it looks very similar to what I've found online. I want a sweet alert to pop up and then when the user clicks the confirm button I want the script to send them back to the homepage. However, this just shows the sweet alert and does not redirect them on close. Also please note Sweet Alert is installed properly. Here's my code:

```
swal({
        title: 'Signed Up!',
        html: 'Thank you for registering',
        type: 'success',
        confirmButtonText: 'Got it!'
      }, function () {
         window.location.href = "index.php";
       });
```

Comment: Would this do?swal({
    title: 'Signed Up!',
    html: 'Thank you for registering',
    type: 'success',
    confirmButtonText: 'Got it!'
}).then(function () {
    window.location.href = "index.php";
});

Comment: Yeah, actually that's pretty close! That works if you click the button, but not if you just click off the alert box or dismiss it in any other way. How would you modify it to also do that?

Comment: I figured it out, you just need to a catch to the function as well, here's my final code:
swal({ title: 'Signed Up!', html: 'Thank you for registering', type: 'success', confirmButtonText: 'Got it!' }).then(function () { window.location.href = "index.php"; }).catch(function () { window.location.href = "index.php"; });

Answer (score 0):

```
swal({
  title: 'Signed Up!',
  html: 'Thank you for registering',
  type: 'success',
  confirmButtonText: 'Got it!'
}).then(function () {
  window.location.href = "index.php";
}, function (dismiss) {
  // dismiss can be 'cancel', 'overlay',
  // 'close', and 'timer'
  if (dismiss === 'cancel') {
    window.location.href = "cancel.php";
  }
});
```

I have not tested this but the documentation says this would work. https://sweetalert2.github.io/